# How would I use multiple classes together without inheritance?

Tags: python, class

I am currently learning classes and applying it as I go but I have come across an issue I am not sure how to get past:

I do not know how would I define a character having a weapon.

I have looked into the problem elsewhere but it always leads to inheritance which I want to avoid as it would not make sense. Is there any way to do this? I will be showing both the relevant code to the issue and then below, the full code for classes used.

## Relevant Code

#### Weapon Class

```
class weapon:

    def __init__ (self):
        <constructor>

    def set_attack (self, attack):
        self.attack = attack

    def get_attack (self):
        return self.attack
```

#### Character Class

```
class character:

    def __init__ (self):
        <constructor>

    def set_attack (self, amount):
        self.attack = amount

    def get_attack (self):
        return self.attack
```

## Full Code

#### Weapon Class

```
class weapon:

    def __init__ (self, name, attack, crit_chance, crit_bonus, rarity, type_bonus):
        self.name = name
        self.attack = attack
        self.crit_chance = crit_chance
        self.crit_bonus = crit_bonus
        self.rarity = rarity
        self.type_bonus = type_bonus

    def set_name (self, name):
        self.name = name

    def set_attack (self, attack):
        self.attack = attack

    def set_crit_chance (self, crit_chance):
        self.crit_chance = crit_chance

    def set_crit_bonus (self, crit_bonus):
        self.crit_bonus = crit_bonus

    def set_rarity (self, rarity):
        self.rarity = rarity

    def set_type_bonus (self, type_bonus):
        self.type_bonus = type_bonus

    def get_name (self):
        return self.name

    def get_attack (self):
        return self.attack

    def get_crit_chance (self):
        return self.crit_chance

    def get_crit_bonus (self):
        return self.crit_bonus

    def get_rarity (self):
        return self.rarity

    def get_type_bonus (self):
        return self.type_bonus
```

#### Character Class

```
class character:

    def __init__ (self, name, max_health, current_health, attack):
        self.name = name
        self.max_health = max_health
        self.current_health = current_health
        self.attack = attack

    def set_name (self, name):
        self.name = name

    def set_max_health (self, amount):
        self.max_amount = amount

    def set_current_health (self, amount):
        self.current_health = amount

    def set_attack (self, amount):
        self.attack = amount

    def get_name (self):
        return self.name

    def get_max_health (self):
        return self.max_health

    def get_current_health (self):
        return self.current_health

    def get_attack (self):
        return self.attack
```

#### Player Class Inheriting From Character Class

```
class player (character):

    def __init__ (self, name, max_health, current_health, attack, money, level, xp):
        super().__init__(name, max_health, current_health, attack)
        self.money = money
        self.level = level
        self.xp = xp

    def set_money (self, amount):
        self.money = amount

    def set_level (self, amount):
        self.level = amount

    def set_xp (self, amount):
        self.xp = amount

    def get_money (self):
        return self.money

    def get_level (self):
        return self.level

    def get_xp (self):
        return self.xp
```

I am expecting the player, which inherits from character, to be able to attack using the value of a weapon object tied to that character.
Any info is appreciated.*emphasized text*

Comment: Add a `weapon` member to your `player` class.

Comment: There is no `weapon` attached to your `player` class. You need to initialize one in your `player`'s constructor and use its `get_attack` method to get attack value.

Comment: You could remove attack from character, and give character a weapon property. Then you'd refer to someplayer.weapon.attack

Comment: You really don't need all those getter and setter methods.

Comment: You can cover both scenarios, a player being attacked, or player attacking someone. Check my answer and see if it makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with you can get rid of all those getters and setters and make your classes as

```
class Weapon:

    def __init__ (self, name, attack, crit_chance, crit_bonus, rarity, type_bonus):
        self.name = name
        self.attack = attack
        self.crit_chance = crit_chance
        self.crit_bonus = crit_bonus
        self.rarity = rarity
        self.type_bonus = type_bonus

class Character:

    def __init__ (self, name, max_health, current_health, attack):
        self.name = name
        self.max_health = max_health
        self.current_health = current_health
        self.attack = attack
```

Then pass a weapon object to your player class, and use that to attack the player, here `weapon` represents the Weapon with the player

```
class Player (character):

    def __init__ (self, name, max_health, current_health, attack, money, level, xp, weapon):
        super().__init__(name, max_health, current_health, attack)
        self.money = money
        self.level = level
        self.xp = xp
        self.weapon = weapon

    #For e.g. A weapon attacks and reduces the current health of the player
    def attack(self):
       self.current_health -= self.weapon.attack
```

Or pass both a weapon and character class object to your player class, `otherplayer` is the Player attacked, and `weapon` is the Weapon with the player

```
class Player (character):

    def __init__ (self, name, max_health, current_health, attack, money, level, xp, otherplayer, weapon):
        super().__init__(name, max_health, current_health, attack)
        self.money = money
        self.level = level
        self.xp = xp
        self.otherplayer = otherplayer
        self.weapon = weapon

    def attack(self):

        self.otherplayer.current_health -= self.weapon.attack
```

Comment: Great, please upvote/ accept my answer if it helped you out :)

Comment: Will do! Thanks again, have a great day

Comment: Thanks man! Don't hesitate to ask if you have further questions!

Comment: Okay well phone is about to die but later on will test it out and ask if need be

Comment: I see you unaccepted my answer! Was something missing?

Comment: I just don't know where to do it on the phone, sorry. Will do it in roughly an hour when I go on pc

Answer (score 0):

The `Character` class would have a field that's an instance of the `Weapon` class, like this:

```py
class Character:

    def __init__ (self, name, max_health, current_health, attack, weapon):
        self.name = name
        self.max_health = max_health
        self.current_health = current_health
        self.attack = attack
        self.weapon = weapon  # this line

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def set_weapon(self, weapon):
        self.weapon = weapon
```

You'd just build a `Weapon` object and pass it to the `Character` object when constructing it (or via the setter method):

```py
weapon = Weapon()
character = Character('Char Name', 100, 100, 20, weapon)
```

Now, as a side note, please name your classes using uppercase for the initial letter, it's a [PEP8 convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names). It helps differentiating class names from instances, otherwise you wouldn't be able to call the instances `weapon` and `character` in my example above.